# Array list stored in Shared preferences, data is being replaced instead of updating

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile-application

I have a `quizAdapter`, after completing the quiz, I have stored scores in shared preferences in the form of a list. Whenever a new quiz has been attempted the history of the quiz in the `ExerciseFragment` should be added to that list. After updating the list it removes old values and only shows the recent attempt.

```
private fun saveScores(correctAnswers: Int, totalQues: Int) {
    exerciseList.add(Exercise(topicName, correctAnswers.toString(), totalQues.toString()))
  
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

    session.writeListInPref(this.context,exerciseList)

    Log.d("veg", exerciseList.toString())
}
```

The code for the Exercise fragment is this

```
  var list = session.readListFromPref(context as Activity) as ArrayList<Exercise>


    if(list.isNotEmpty())
    {
        adapter.setExList(list)
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(list.size)
    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(context as Activity, "No quiz attempted yet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Comment: Have you verified that `session.writeListInPref(this.context,exerciseList)` works correctly, i.e. it adds to the preference entry instead of replacing it? You might want to attach the code for that method.

Comment: User Gson Library for serialise your list and save as string in shared preferences.
Deserialise the shared preferences string and add new item in list.

[link](https://github.com/google/gson)

Answer (score 0):

> Found the solution by just reading first from ´shared preference´ and after updating it by calling the add method of the list

```
private fun saveScores(correctAnswers: Int, totalQues: Int) {
    exerciseList = session.readListFromPref(this.context) as ArrayList<Exercise>
    exerciseList.add(Exercise(topicName, correctAnswers.toString(), totalQues.toString()))
   // binding.exRv.adapter = adapter

    session.writeListInPref(this.context,exerciseList)

    Log.d("veg", exerciseList.size.toString())
}
```